# Kryo byte-level append

Tags: java, database, cassandra, kryo

I'm storing JSON in a table (really a Cassandra column family) like this:

```
 ____________________________________________________________________
|                 || prop1               | prop2               | ... |
|  collection_id  || [val1, val2, ...]   | [val1, val2, ...]   | ... |
|_________________||_____________________|_____________________|_____|
```

So an object `{ prop1: 1, prop2: 2 }` would be stored:

```
 ____________________________________________
|                 || prop1         | prop2   |
|  collection_id  || [1]           | [2]     |
|_________________||_______________|_________|
```

To save space, I'm going to Kryo-serialize each array of property values. My worry is that, when I perform a write, I would need to first load ALL arrays of property values, then add my new object's values to each array, and then push every array back to the database. If I've already stored a lot of events, that can be very expensive!

Is there a way to "append" new to values to each array in Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

Append is available with Cassandra's native collections: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_list_t.html  so instead of using Kryo to serialize the collection, you should just serialize the elements.